# Is there any possibilities that getting documents that's been shared with the current user!

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Any search API that shows shared with me documents been used with SPFX

Comment: This is a poor question that seems to have no effort put in to asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Graph API from Microsoft you can list all the shared document with the signed in user, this only works if you have SharePoint Online and OneDrive. Have a look at this reference page that is describing this endpoint [List items shared with the signed-in user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_sharedwithme)

[API Reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/v1-overview)

[Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) - Great tool for getting started and exploring the API and it's endpoints.

Comment: yes if it is one drive then the flow is OK with API "/me/drive/sharedWithMe", but for share point online is there any search API for shared documents

Comment: Kindly find the answer for the share point search API for the shared documents

/_api/search/query?querytext='author:UserName'&(IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") ViewableByExternalUsers=TRUE&selectproperties='Author,Title,Path,HitHighlightedProperties,FileType,IsDocument,ParentLink,LastModifiedTime'&rowlimit='90'

Comment: The `beta/me/drive/sharedWithMe` API also returns files shared from SharePoint Online. Tested with a document in the standard Documents library - worked.